# Wrongly big numbers when use multiple of Sum, Count aggregations in annotate

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have these models:

```
User:
    email = EmailField()

Payment:
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    sum = DecimalField()

GuestAccount:
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    guest = ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to get user emails, amount of money that came from every user
and number of its guests accounts.

My query:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    money=Sum('payment__sum'),
    guests_number=Count('guestaccount')
).values('email', 'money', 'guests_number')
```

But `money` and `guests_number` in the result of the query are bigger then they really are:

```
{'guests_number': 0,  'email': 'a@b.cd',            'money': None}
{'guests_number': 20, 'email': 'user1@mail.com',    'money': Decimal('6600.00')}
{'guests_number': 4,  'email': 'user1000@test.com', 'money': Decimal('2500.00')}
{'guests_number': 0,  'email': 'zzzz@bbbbb.com',    'money': None}
```

I noticed that I get correct data if I split the query into 2 separate queries:

```
User.objects.annotate(money=Sum('payment__sum')).values('email', 'money')
User.objects.annotate(guests_number=Count('guestaccount')).values('email', 'guests_number')
```

Correct result of 1st half:

```
{'email': 'a@b.cd',            'money': None}
{'email': 'user1@mail.com',    'money': Decimal('1650.00')}
{'email': 'user1000@test.com', 'money': Decimal('1250.00')}
{'email': 'zzzz@bbbbb.com',    'money': None}
```

Correct result of 2nd half:

```
{'email': 'a@b.cd',            'guests_number': 0}
{'email': 'user1@mail.com',    'guests_number': 4}
{'email': 'user1000@test.com', 'guests_number': 2}
{'email': 'zzzz@bbbbb.com',    'guests_number': 0}
```

Also I noticed that I can add `distinct=True` in `Count` aggregation:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    money=Sum('payment__sum'),
    guests_number=Count('guestaccount', distinct=True)
).values('email', 'money', 'guests_number')
```

It fixes `guests_number`:

```
{'guests_number': 0, 'email': 'a@b.cd',            'money': None}
{'guests_number': 4, 'email': 'user1@mail.com',    'money': Decimal('6600.00')}
{'guests_number': 2, 'email': 'user1000@test.com', 'money': Decimal('2500.00')}
{'guests_number': 0, 'email': 'zzzz@bbbbb.com',    'money': None}
```

Unfortunatly, there are no `distinct` parameter in `Sum` aggregation.

What is wrong with my query? How to fix these numbers getting bigger with every aggregation in annotate?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you do `User.objects.values('email').annotate(money=Sum('payment__sum'), guests_number=Count('guestaccount'))`?

Comment: @ShangWang your query produces the same wrong result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Raw SQL query investigation showed that the problem comes from multiple LEFT OUTER JOINs. So I ended up with raw SQL:

```
User.objects.extra(select={
                "money": """
                    SELECT SUM("website_payment"."sum")
                    FROM "website_payment"
                    WHERE "website_user"."id" = "website_payment"."user_id"
                """,
                "guests_number": """
                    SELECT COUNT("guests_guestaccount"."id")
                    FROM "guests_guestaccount"
                    WHERE "website_user"."id" = "guests_guestaccount"."user_id"
                """,
            }
        ).values('email', 'money', 'guests_number')
```

But I need to annotate these fields into queried objects and `extra` don't do it.